# What cable do I need to perform this connection

Tags: audio, cable, tv

I want to output audio from my laptop to my TV. I output the video using VGA.

Here is the picture from my manual. [image]

I need options 6. The one where there's a VGA cable and a sound cable.

I don't understand what's the input on the TV.
I'm pretty sure that the output from the laptop is a 3.5 audio cable.

Can someone tell me, what the hell is that audio input slot for option 6.

Just in case, here is the link to the manual: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201104/20110426143830850/BN68-01900B-00L02-110426.pdf

P.S. The picture is from page 13 of the manual. The TV model is Samsung LN46B610

Here is a picture of the back of the TV[image]

The slot that corresponds to option 6 is right of the blue VGA  cable

Comment: Do you have an actual photo of the back of the TV.

Comment: Off topic for EE. That said, ten bucks says the actual jack is a regular 3.5mm one. 1, you cut off the manual part 6, and 2, you don't show the actual tv back

Comment: nono. that's the entire part 6. I'll make a picture of the back of the TV now. give me 10 minutes please

Comment: I found a picture of the board on eBay. It's a regular 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So this means it's a 3.5 to 3.5 cable? Is the TV female and the laptop male?

Comment: It looks to me as if the audio cable is a standard 3.5mm stereo male to 3.5mm stereo male cable.  This is readily available from many places or you can make your own cable.

Comment: A "patch" or "aux" cable. Dollar store.

Comment: "VGA with audio" is a standard VGA cable with a 3.5mm audio cable stuck to it.

Answer (score 0):

A regular 3.5mm stereo male to male cable, typically known as a patch or aux cable, is needed. The jack is a 3.5mm trs connector.